# Facebook FB.login() Popup Won't Close in IE8

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, popup

I've searched for answers to this -- seems like all the answers relate to the old Facebook API so the solutions are no longer relevant.

The problem I'm having: I've got a custom Facebook tab which has a button on it that, when clicked, triggers FB.login(). The way it should work is: user clicks to log in, popup comes up to authorize the app, user clicks authorize, the popup closes. This flow works correctly on all browsers except IE8 and below. On IE8, the user clicks to log in, the popup comes up to authorize the app, the user clicks authorize, then the content INSIDE the popup refreshes with the content from the redirect URL. Needless to say, this is not the desired experience for IE8 users :(

I've tried everything I could find: doublechecked that there are no javascript errors, ensured that there is a valid channel file, etc. Nothing appears to fix it. Everything is happening through secure (https), so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

I've been trying to fix this for DAYS now; any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Are IE7 and IE9 working fine?

Comment: IE9 is fine. IE7 doesn't work. It's IE8 and below that has the error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure fb-root element is only once in your page , I have faced this issues and when i made sure that fb-root div is only once the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a p3p header in all responses from your web server. Please see: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

By "the content INSIDE the popup refreshes with the content from the redirect URL" do you mean that you are passing a redirect URL? If so, don't do that. The popups work using some cross-domain JavaScript magic with a specially constructed redirect URL. If you put your own, then the popups may break.

Also, make sure you're setting a proper channelUrl when you call FB.init().

Comment: Sorry for any confusion: we're not passing an additional redirect URL.  I guess by "redirect" I meant that the popup is reloading the page that initially called FB.login() (rather than closing the popup and triggering the auth.login event).

    `FB.login(function(){},{scope:'email,user_location,user_birthday'});` is the function that's called onclick.

Comment: Also, In FB.init(), we're linking to a channel.php file with the following inside:

    `<?php
 $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$cache_expire);
 header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$cache_expire) . ' GMT');
 ?>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> `  
Is that correct?